# getting the ID generated by sleuth in response of header section also

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have developed a rest service and I have used the sleuth in my spring boot rest project which generates the random id for every API request in logs which is working perfectly, now the point is that the id which is getting generated in logs by adding sleuth dependency, how can I get the same id in response in headers section of that API request also, Please advise how can I achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to add them manually, they will be added for you by Sleuth.
See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.1.x/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_http_client_integration
Just inject a bean of one of the mentioned HTTP clients and you're good to go.

Hope that helps! :)